# Do I have to get a transit visa for Spain ? I'm travelling to Switzerland

Tags: visas, schengen, transit, spain, switzerland

I'm living in Canada holding my PR card. I have plan to go Switzerland.
I got my Swiss visa multiple entry. But I booked my flight Toronto to Spain then 4 hours stay in Spain, Barcelona. Then Spain to Switzerland.
Do I have to get a transit visa for Spain?

Answer (score 4):

No.  Spain and Switzerland are both in the Schengen area.  Your Swiss visa permits you to enter the Schengen area, anywhere.  You will do that in Spain.

Comment: when I applied for visa they were asked me what is the first entry and I gave Swiss as answer Is that ok too ? Also other thing to mention that I have Sri Lankan Passport and living in Canada PR card holder

Comment: It is perfectly normal for an itinerary to be changed a bit, depending on e.g. flight availability. As long as the justification for the trip remains valid and Switzerland still is your main destination you should be fine.

Comment: @MotorWars Arne is correct.  Changing your itinerary slightly (for example because you found a more favorable itinerary with a different airline) should not cause any problems.